# Join and Having - get the accounts that appear more than once in the contract table

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, having

I'm trying to get the accounts that appear more than once in the contract table, regardless of the number of times it's joined in the c_map table.

```
CREATE TABLE cntrct (
  cntrct_id VARCHAR(10),
  account_id varchar(10)
);
CREATE TABLE c_map (
  cntrct_id VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO cntrct VALUES (1,'a');
insert into cntrct values (2,'b');
insert into cntrct values (3,'c');
insert into cntrct values (4,'b');

INSERT INTO c_map VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO c_map VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO c_map VALUES (1);
insert into c_map values (2);
insert into c_map values (2);
insert into c_map values (2);
insert into c_map values (3);
insert into c_map values (3);
insert into c_map values (3);
commit;

select ct.account_id
from cntrct ct, c_map cm
where ct.cntrct_id = cm.cntrct_id
group by ct.account_id
having count(ct.account_id)> 1
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cec1b7/4

I'm expecting an output of:

```
 b
```

But instead I'm getting all of them.

How can I limit it so it doesn't take the c_map table into consideration when running the having count()>1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> get the accounts that appear more than once in the contract table, regardless of the number of times it's joined in the c_map table.

Why join at all? The information you want is in the contract table:

```
select account_id
from cntrct 
group by account_id
having count(*) > 1
```

*Maybe* you want to filter the dataset on contract id that exists in the map table. If so, I would recommend  `exists`:

```
select account_id
from cntrct c
where exists (select 1 from c_map m where m.cntrct_id = c.cntrct_id)
group by account_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: because it's simplified.  I need to take into consideration a condition in the c_map table that isn't represented here.  The concept is the same though.